# Linkedin oauth2 api returns http status 451 and serviceErrorCode 65900

Tags: linkedin-api, pac4j

I use linkedin as a way to log in, in short, "Login to MyAPP with Linkedin account"

But recently we found that the login is not working properly, code error when using oauth2 to login.

```
{"serviceErrorCode":65900,"message":"Restricted Location","status":451}
```

Base on status code 451, i guess it's a policy issues.

Are related API services no longer available to mainland China? Or api url changed? If so, how to fix this issue?

The same app deployed in other regions outside mainland China works fine, only the instance in mainland China is having issues

Thanks for answer

Comment: From my understanding, the API has been restricted in China.

Comment: @Eric Base on the news, they are spinning off their China business from global, so i believe it has been restricted, but i need an official answer to confirm it. and linkedin custom service told me to ask "tech" question in stackoverflow...no one answer it yet uitl you did... thanks anyway